# iOS Application Guidelines

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

I am unsure whether my application will be rejected or not so I am not sure whether I should continue with the development of it. Basically without giving a whole bunch of information it will display "fake phones around you" (ie. their cellular hotspot). I will not be using any private API's or such but there will be an option to "crack" their wifi password but it is purely a prank. Is this allowed?

Answer (score 2):

From Apple's Guidelines:

```
2.14 Apps that are intended to provide trick or fake functionality that are not clearly marked as such will be rejected
```

It appears that as long as you clearly state that this is a prank and no phones/wifis are being hacked, you can do it.

Note: Apple may reject you for any reason if they wish.

Comment: Thank you very much @Wayfarer, are those guidelines only available to members of the development member thing since I cannot find it.

Comment: I had to login to access them here https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html but I'm not sure if you need to be paid or not (I am). You can probably find them elsewhere on the Internet.